# Combinations problem about multiset. Multiple ways.

Tags: permutations, combinations

`Determine the number of 6-combinations of multiset s = {3·a, 4·b, 5·c}`

I can solve this problem by inclusion-exclusion principle, but is there any more clever way to solve it? (e.g. By solving the 12-permutations first...anyway)

Learning "Introductory Combinatorics".

Comment: Stars-and-bars with Inclusion-exclusion is the standard approach, but it does admittedly become tedious and messy as there are more options.  A braindead approach that always works is generating functions, but this is just disguised brute force that would typically require computer help.  Look at the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$

Comment: As for "by solving the 12-permutations first", no... that does not work, at least not without a great deal of struggle and shoehorning.  It gets too much into case hell, not only trying to care about the arrangements of the six "used" elements but also the arrangements of the *unused* elements.